# Laravel Echo and Laravel Echo server and socket: Distinguish join and leave events in server side

Tags: laravel, sockets, laravel-echo

I am building a web service for a mobile application. I need to know which mobile users are online. I implemented this by Laravel echo- laravel echo server-socket io and redis. Every thing works and by presence channel the client listens to the events.

The problem is, the leave and join events are on client side, while when a user leaves the channel, I need to remove it from a list stored in Redis, In fact I need to know that which of the join or leave occurs in server side not client side in order to be able to update the online users in Redis.

How can I do this?

## My solutions

### Solution 1

If there is any implementation of `here` method in server side which returns  the online users, it may work, in fact I can compare the my list with `here` to get the latest update.

### Solution 2

When an event happens for a user, if that user already exists in my list in the Redis, clearly it is a leave event, because users can be online exactly once at any moment, and if the user doesn't exist in the list, so it must be a join, because no one can join if it is already on the list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to know if you are using a front end Framework like Vue /Angular of you are just writing raw JS.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Presence Channels](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting#presence-channels) for this functionality.

Watch this Laracast [Episode 8](https://laracasts.com/series/get-real-with-laravel-echo/episodes/8) video, you can adapt the examples there with your offline user list.

I suggest pushing the `user.id` of an online user into an `participants` array list using channel `here`, `joining`, `leaving` hooks as the video demonstrates.

When outputting your full list of `users`, you could check if they are online using [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const participants = [4, 34, 57, 70]

for (user of users) {

  if( participants.includes(user.id) ) {
   // The user is online, Set an online style or something
  }

}
```